# Include third party libraries in source tree

Tags: c++, development-environment, cmake

My CMake C++ project depends on several commercial libraries (only libs and headers are available). I want an easy way to include these packages in my source tree.

I have tried the following options:

1. Use svn:externals and provide these libraries in a **thirdparty** folder of the source tree. Pros: easy. Cons: slow download, all or nothing.
2. Has a README file detailing what package is required for what option in my CMake. Developers will have to download and unpack to the right place. Pros: fast download, select only the package necessary. Cons: complicated.

Is there a way for me to deploy these packages to the developers automatically?

The workflow that I want:

1. Developer choose an option in CMake e.g. USE_LIBRARY_A
2. Developer hit Configure
3. Package is downloaded and put in the right place in the source tree
4. Developer hit Generate
5. Solution/Makefile is ready for compilation

I guess what I want is similar to easy_install in Python or rubygems in Ruby.

Comment: It sounds like this is more about your VCS than about CMake.  Make sure you have some way of recording the version of the external library in use at various points in your own project's timeline (e.g. subrepos in hg handle this) so that you can 1) correctly get the state of your project at a specific point and 2) upgrade or avoid upgrading those external libraries (including across multiple branches) as your project requires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired workflow can be achieved by adding the third party libraries as [CMake external projects](http://www.kitware.com/media/html/BuildingExternalProjectsWithCMake2.8.html).

The `ExternalProject_Add` command lets you automatically download, build and install third-party libraries.